# StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: Mysql2::Error: Table 'hiredjob_development.admins' doesn't exist:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, devise, database-migration

I am a new ROR developer. We are developing an application using Rails and AngularJS. A brief background of what I was trying to do:
   Another developer developed an application (partial) named hiredjob. I have to continue development with his application changing the name of the application to hiredtoday and also changing all the models from admin_X to X . For that following is the sequence of steps I follow:
   Method 1:

---

1. Copy the old hiredjob application to a new application hiredtoday.
2. Delete all db/migrate.
3. rails generate devise admin.
4. rake db:migrate gives error

*Error from `rake db:migrate`:*

```
home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/devise-
3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:485:in `raise_no_devise_method_error!': Admin does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb' (RuntimeError)
```

On searching solution for above on the internet, I comment `devise_for :admins` in `config/route.rb`

6. After which on running rake db:migrate again I got an error.

*Error is as follow:*

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'hiredjob_development.admins' doesn't exist: ALTER TABLE 'admins' ADD 'email' varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `query'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `block in execute'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `execute'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:573:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:572:in `each'
    /home/arshi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:572:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
```

Note: I have also tried to do run:  `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`. But still does not work.

Comment: can you paste the code generated by number 3, including file name. also, is the migration generated by number three your only migration at this point? and, i'm pretty sure it's irrelevant, but it looks like you haven't changed you db.yml to reflect the change in the name of the app.

Comment: The output after rails generate devise admin is:

Comment: invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160205073228_add_devise_to_admins.rb
      insert    app/models/admin.rb
       route  devise_for :admins
Yes this is the first migration for the new application hiredtoday

Comment: How to change db.yml?

Comment: look in config/db.yaml i believe. i don't think it's actually you're problem, but it's still worth changing it.

Comment: @Ian I tried changing that too but again error

Answer (score 1):

i think you are getting this error because devise depends on the table already having been created. you need to:

1) delete the devise migration

2) write a migration to create the admins table http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table

3) regenerate the devise migration.

Comment: but I did not create any explicit migrations

Comment: precisely. the code you ran in your third step created a migration. unfortunately, it is a migration that is designed to alter a table that does not yet exist, the admins. you need to write the migration that creates that table. have you tried the steps i laid out? if they failed, what were the errors?

Comment: 1. rails destroy devise admin 2. rails generate model admin(also tried admins) gives error : The model name 'admins' was recognized as a plural, using the singular 'admin' instead. Override with --force-plural or setup custom inflection rules for this noun before running the generator.
      invoke  active_record
The name 'Admin' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.

Comment: ah, we're not even worried about the model yet. don't run 'rails generate model admin' instead use 'rails generate migration create_admins' you need to migrate the table into existence before devise can alter it.

Comment: After rails generate migration create_admins , when i do rails generate devise admin it gives error: invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160205083458_devise_create_admins.rb
The name 'Admin' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.

Comment: have you deleted the code you generated for the model?

Comment: the output for rails generate model admin or rails generate migration create_admins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102672/discussion-between-ian-root-and-ashi).